# Defining uncertainty intervals in an objective function

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimization

I have an objective function to use in python scipy minimize or leastsq method.

```
def residual(x):

    # Total population,  N.
    return np.sum((infections(x) - 300) ** 2)
```

Assume the function `infections(x)` returns the last value of an ODE trajectory array, which is the equilibrium of that ODE solution. Now I want to minimize to find the parameter that best fits so that the equilibrium value is 300. Hence why I am subtracting 300, squaring and then summing. But if I want an uncertainty interval of 20% on each side, so the equilibrium value can be anywhere from 240 to 360 and its still fine. How would this be incorporated into the syntax for this objective function?

Comment: "still fine" is not something you can optimize for, because it is not precise enough. You could either make it flat, so that 300, or 302 or 360 is *exactly* the same, or you could weight or change the derivative around the target, so that 300 is still best, but a +2 count less if it is, say, below 360, and more if it is above 360.

Comment: Yes, but how does this get implemented in the function with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your residuals flat around the threshold value (`300`).

For example, you could just compute your target `(infections(x) - thres) ** 2` and set it to, say, 0, when below the squared threshold with the tolerance (20% or `0.2`) `(thres * tol) ** 2`.

```py
def residual(x):
    tol = 0.2  # 20% tolerance
    thres = 300  # Threshold value
    min_val = (thres * tol) ** 2
    target = (infections(x) - thres) ** 2
    target[target < min_value] = 0
    return np.sum(target)
```

This will get you a flat-around-target residual function.

You could replace `0` with a different function for different mathematical properties, but the code would otherwise be very similar:

```py
def residual(x):
    tol = 0.2  # 20% tolerance
    thres = 300  # Threshold value
    min_val = (thres * tol) ** 2
    target = (infections(x) - thres) ** 2
    mask = target < min_value
    target[mask] = np.log(1 + target[mask])  #
    return np.sum(target)
```